# Show hidden div when choose any option from select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select list with `id="select"` and a hidden div. When I choose any option from select list, need to show div (`id="choosen"`)

Help me please

```
<select id="select" name="select" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" title="выберите">
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>

 <!-- show this div -->
 <div id="сhoosen" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Post some code buddy..

Comment: Rephrase your question, As of now no one understand what is the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3hffe7wg/

Comment: please check the updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```html
<p>Select</p>

<select id="select" onchange="selFunction()">
  <option value="100">100
  <option value="200">200
  <option value="300">300
  <option value="400">400
</select>


<p id="chosen" style="display:none;"></p>

<style>
  #chosen{   
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
  text-align:center;}
  
</style>

<script>
function selFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("select").value;
    var result = document.getElementById("chosen");
      result.style.display = "block"; //make #chosen visible
      result.innerHTML = x ; //output selected value
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("#select").change(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     $('#choosen').text(val);
 });
```